# How to reduce delay in playing m3u8 video through mpmovieplayercontroller

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Iam playing m3u8 url(i.e from Wowza Streaming Engine) through mpmovieplayercontroller in ipad. But initially I can observe some delay in playing video. Please help me how can I reduce this delay time in playing the video.

Here is my code:

```
urlStr=@"http://192.168.1.14:1935/live/teststream/playlist.m3u8";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];

videoPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[videoPlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
videoPlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
//[videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
[_session.previewView addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
[_session.previewView bringSubviewToFront:videoPlayer.view];
videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,768, 512);

[videoPlayer play];
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.